# Firestore - recommended way to write to a document and tell its size?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of document in Firestore.
I want to write data to a map in a document, but once it exceeds a certain size (number of entries) - I want to create another document and write to it.

What would be a recommended way to do that?
How can I avoid reading a document (to get the map size) after each write?

Comment: There is no API for getting the sizes of anything.  And there is no easy way to compute it other than to do it yourself using the data you have available. The best resource you have available is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

Comment: If you are going to have a very large map and you need to know how many elements are in it, then what you probably really want is a subcollection whose size you can count: WIth this design, you are no longer bounded by the size of a single document. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries

Comment: A sub-collection is a solution, but at high cost: if we talk about a chat app, it seems more reasonable to store a map of messages in a single document, and when it is "quite large" move to the next document...

Comment: It's your only viable alternative for things that can grow unbounded.  Unbounded sets of data are supposed to be modeled as collections in Firestore.  The system simply does not work well at all if you try to shard data over multiple documents.  You can do that if you really want, but it will just cause you problems in the future.  That's a different type of cost that you'll have to pay.

Comment: Indeed it complicates things, but I feel that for the most common scenario - where people read only the last couple of messages (and maybe scrolling through couple of dozens of messages), it would be better to store these in a single document, and upon request - load older documents...

Comment: So [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) would not work for that case?

Comment: indeed, the original question was in order to figure out when to write to the next document (without reading it on every update)

Comment: So you're saying it's not viable to move the map into a subcollection of individual documents and query them with pagination so you don't have to load the entire thing?  That's how it's supposed to work for the use case you're describing.  As I said, you're just not supposed to cram data into a minimal number of documents - you won't find any good solutions there and it will just cause you problems.  If you're not willing to move unbounded data into a collection, then Firestore might not be the right database for you.